Sampling real orthogonal matrix with a given set of eigenvalues?
Suppose I'm given a set of $n$ conjugate pairs $\lambda_i, \overline{\lambda_i}$ of eigenvalues on the unit circle. How can I sample a real orthogonal matrix which has these eigenvalues?
One way could be rejection sampling by using QR decomposition of random Gaussian matrices, that's too slow to be practical for $n>2$ so I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way.

Let $\lambda_i=a_i+b_i\sqrt{-1}$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are real numbers. In theory, you may generate a random $2n\times2n$ orthogonal matrix $U$ first, and then construct the orthogonal matrix as $$Q=U\left[\pmatrix{a_1&-b_1\ b_1&a_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus\pmatrix{a_n&-b_n\ b_n&a_n}\right]U^T.$$

@user1551 does it matter if U is random element of O(n) or SO(n)? Does it mean the result is a member of O(n) or SO(n) respectively?

Both $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$ are OK. The result is always a member of $SO(n)$, as its determinant is $\prod_{i=1}^n(a_i^2+b_i^2)=\prod_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i|^2=1$.

@user1551 I see. So if I sample $\lambda_i$ uniformly from complex unit circle, the result is not a uniform member of $SO(n)$ is it? I was surprised to see that SO(n) prefers rotations close to $0$ and $\pi$ -- https://mathoverflow.net/a/477232/7655

(I suppose that you meant $SO(2n)$, as the matrix has $2n$ eigenvalues.) Provided that Girko’s result in your linked MO question is correct (which I believe so, although I am not familiar with it), you are right: the resulting special orthogonal matrix is not uniformly distributed in $SO(2n)$, although the angles are. Girko’s result indicates that you cannot have both (unless $n=1$).
